# Protect direct access to image folder

Tags: php

So I've my images folder, and I protect it with a index.php file with no text or anything. So they can't browse the images. But is this enough as security? I've tried to disable the url with php but without any success. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: If you need the images accessible there's not much else you can do. If not then if you're serving your PHP with Apache you can add an `.htaccess` file to `deny ALL` access to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to prevent the directory content from being displayed is to disable directory listing.

Don't place an index file in the directory you like to prevent from public access. Create a `.htaccess` file add `Options -Indexes` to it. This would cause a http 403 error when you point to the directory.